# concrete5 content import CIF

Tags: concrete5

I am trying to import a large number of pages into concrete 5 using a package and the content import format CIF explained in this documentation:

http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/concrete5-5.5-content-import-format-sample-content-and-starting-/

The main problem I am having is that images are not being imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<concrete5-cif version="1.0">
<pages>
  <page
      name="Product Name"
      path="/products/productX"
      filename="" 
      pagetype="product"
      description=""
      package="">
        <area name="Main">
            <block type="image" name="">
                <data table="btContentImage">
                    <record>
                        <fID>{ccm:export:file:filename.jpg}</fID>
```

This is resulting in an `image not found` note on the frontend and no images in the filemanager and files folders.

The files are in `/packages/mycontent/files/filename.jpg`

I have set 777 permissions everywhere. I have also tried: `<fID>{ccm:export:image:filename.jpg}</fID>`

Why are these images not importing?

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I think for the import script the files need to be in

```
/config/install/packages/mycontent/files/filename.jpg
```

also ensure you have the extra content with the record, failing to include those may result in a database error when adding the files.

```
<fOnstateID/>
<maxWidth><![CDATA[0]]></maxWidth>
<maxHeight><![CDATA[0]]></maxHeight>
<externalLink><![CDATA[]]></externalLink>
<internalLinkCID><![CDATA[0]]></internalLinkCID>
<altText><![CDATA[]]></altText>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am installing content as part of the package, not at install. +1 for the info

Comment: does the package have a theme, the last bit of that page suggests it would be need to be in "content_files/" directory (Within the full content swap section)

Comment: My understanding was that the files should be within files/ next to the content.xml. I will investigate putting the files within the theme and the content.xml in the package. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I set up a `starting point` and had to import all the content (and images) as an install. With this folder structure:

```
content/install/packages/mypackage/controller.php
content/install/packages/mypackage/content.xml
content/install/packages/mypackage/files/image.jpg
```

**Controller:**

```
class MypackageStartingPointPackage extends StartingPointPackage {
  protected $pkgHandle = 'mypackage';
  public function getPackageName() {
    return t('My Content Import');
  }
  public function getPackageDescription() {
    return t('My website including content.');
  }
}
```

I couldn't get the CIF file to work either as part of a package or a theme.

When I have more time I will research the difference in the inheritance between a starting point and a normal package using an instance of

```
 Loader::library('content/importer');
```